# Facing problem while running api in Mule 3

Tags: mule, mulesoft, mule-esb, apikit

STILL NOT SOLVED, DOES ANYONE KNOW HOW TO SOLVE IT. the application must be running in mule 3.9.1. thanks everyone

I did a RAML design in anypoint studio and that works fine with runtime 4.3.

However, this same design must also run in runtime 3.9.1. I made some changes so the apikit in 3.9.1 can creates the implementation flow, so far so good.

The issue is when I try to run the project (without any further implementations) I get an error:

> Raml parser uncaught exception

How can I fix this? I tried with the same raml design in version 3.9.3 and it works fine on that.

Below I will add the errors console:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.mule.modules.oauth2.provider.service.StoreCleaningService.dispose(StoreCleaningService.java:84) ~[mule-module-security-oauth2-provider-1.7.5.jar:?]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor20.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.phases.DefaultLifecyclePhase.applyLifecycle(DefaultLifecyclePhase.java:230) ~[mule-core-3.9.1-20220127.jar:3.9.1-20220127]
    ... 36 more
INFO  2022-07-06 13:41:55,161 [main] org.mule.config.spring.MuleArtifactContext: Closing org.mule.config.spring.MuleArtifactContext@59371066: startup date [Wed Jul 06 13:41:52 CEST 2022]; root of context hierarchy
ERROR 2022-07-06 13:41:55,161 [main] org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication: null
org.mule.module.apikit.exception.ApikitRuntimeException: Invalid API descriptor -- errors found: 1

Raml parser uncaught exception: org.raml.yagi.framework.nodes.StringNodeImpl cannot be cast to org.raml.yagi.framework.nodes.KeyValueNode

    at org.mule.module.apikit.parser.ParserWrapperV2.validate(ParserWrapperV2.java:73) ~[mule-module-apikit-3.9.1.jar:?]
    at org.mule.module.apikit.ParserService.validateRaml(ParserService.java:86) ~[mule-module-apikit-3.9.1.jar:?]
    at org.mule.module.apikit.AbstractConfiguration.initialise(AbstractConfiguration.java:112) ~[mule-module-apikit-3.9.1.jar:?]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor19.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.phases.DefaultLifecyclePhase.applyLifecycle(DefaultLifecyclePhase.java:230) ~[mule-core-3.9.1-20220127.jar:3.9.1-20220127]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.phases.MuleContextInitialisePhase.applyLifecycle(MuleContextInitialisePhase.java:71) ~[mule-core-3.9.1-20220127.jar:3.9.1-20220127]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleCallback.doApplyLifecycle(RegistryLifecycleCallback.java:108) ~[mule-core-3.9.1-20220127.jar:3.9.1-20220127]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleCallback.onTransition(RegistryLifecycleCallback.java:78) ~[mule-core-3.9.1-20220127.jar:3.9.1-20220127]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager.invokePhase(AbstractLifecycleManager.java:146) ~[mule-core-3.9.1-20220127.jar:3.9.1-20220127]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager.fireLifecycle(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:134) ~[mule-core-3.9.1-20220127.jar:3.9.1-20220127]
    at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistry.fireLifecycle(AbstractRegistry.java:150) ~[mule-core-3.9.1-20220127.jar:3.9.1-20220127]
    at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistry.initialise(AbstractRegistry.java:116) ~[mule-core-3.9.1-20220127.jar:3.9.1-20220127]
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.createSpringRegistry(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:177) ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.9.1-20220127.jar:3.9.1-20220127]
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:100) ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.9.1-20220127.jar:3.9.1-20220127]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:43) ~[mule-core-3.9.1-20220127.jar:3.9.1-20220127]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69) ~[mule-core-3.9.1-20220127.jar:3.9.1-20220127]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.start(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:155) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.9.1-20220127.jar:3.9.1-20220127]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleDeploymentService.start(MuleDeploymentService.java:135) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.9.1-20220127.jar:3.9.1-20220127]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleContainer.start(MuleContainer.java:172) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.9.1-20220127.jar:3.9.1-20220127]
    at org.mule.tooling.server.application.ApplicationDeployer.main(ApplicationDeployer.java:15) ~[tooling-support-3.9.1.jar:?]
INFO  2022-07-06 13:41:55,171 [main] org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication: App 'test-3.9.1' never started, nothing to dispose of
INFO StatusLogger Found logging config for application 'test-3.9.1' at 'file:/C:/Local/mule3-workspace/.mule/apps/test-3.9.1/classes/log4j2.xml'
INFO StatusLogger Log4j appears to be running in a Servlet environment, but there's no log4j-web module available. If you want better web container support, please add the log4j-web JAR to your web archive or server lib directory.
@4e25154f,component=Loggers,name=,subtype=RingBuffer, org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@4e25154f,component=Loggers,name=org.mule,subtype=RingBuffer, org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@4e25154f,component=Loggers,name=org.jetel,subtype=RingBuffer, org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@4e25154f,component=Loggers,name=Tracking,subtype=RingBuffer, org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@4e25154f,component=Loggers,name=com.mulesoft,subtype=RingBuffer, org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@4e25154f,component=Loggers,name=org.springframework.beans.factory,subtype=RingBuffer, org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@4e25154f,component=Loggers,name=org.apache,subtype=RingBuffer, org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@4e25154f,component=Loggers,name=org.apache.cxf,subtype=RingBuffer]

TRACE StatusLogger Using DummyNanoClock for nanosecond timestamps.
DEBUG StatusLogger Reconfiguration complete for context[name=test-3.9.1] at URI C:\Local\mule3-workspace\.mule\apps\test-3.9.1\classes\log4j2.xml (org.mule.module.launcher.log4j2.MuleLoggerContext@4458ecb8) with optional ClassLoader: null
DEBUG StatusLogger Shutdown hook enabled. Registering a new one.
DEBUG StatusLogger LoggerContext[name=test-3.9.1, org.mule.module.launcher.log4j2.MuleLoggerContext@4458ecb8] started OK.
ERROR 2022-07-06 13:41:55,755 [main] org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer: 
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Failed to deploy artifact 'test-3.9.1', see below        +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentInitException: ApikitRuntimeException: Invalid API descriptor -- errors found: 1

Raml parser uncaught exception: org.raml.yagi.framework.nodes.StringNodeImpl cannot be cast to org.raml.yagi.framework.nodes.KeyValueNode

    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:220) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.9.1-20220127.jar:3.9.1-20220127]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper$2.execute(ArtifactWrapper.java:64) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.9.1-20220127.jar:3.9.1-20220127]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.executeWithinArtifactClassLoader(ArtifactWrapper.java:137) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.9.1-20220127.jar:3.9.1-20220127]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.init(ArtifactWrapper.java:59) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.9.1-20220127.jar:3.9.1-20220127]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:72) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.9.1-20220127.jar:3.9.1-20220127]
    
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.deployPackedApps(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:283) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.9.1-20220127.jar:3.9.1-20220127]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.start(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:155) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.9.1-20220127.jar:3.9.1-20220127]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleDeploymentService.start(MuleDeploymentService.java:135) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.9.1-20220127.jar:3.9.1-20220127]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleContainer.start(MuleContainer.java:172) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.9.1-20220127.jar:3.9.1-20220127]
    at org.mule.tooling.server.application.ApplicationDeployer.main(ApplicationDeployer.java:15) ~[tooling-support-3.9.1.jar:?]
Caused by: org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException: Failed to invoke lifecycle phase "initialise" on object: org.mule.module.apikit.Configuration@3fda8dae (org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException) (org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:49) ~[mule-core-3.9.1-20220127.jar:3.9.1-20220127]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69) ~[mule-core-3.9.1-20220127.jar:3.9.1-20220127]
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory$1.configure(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:89) ~[mule-core-3.9.1-20220127.jar:3.9.1-20220127]
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.doCreateMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:222) ~[mule-core-3.9.1-20220127.jar:3.9.1-20220127]
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:81) ~[mule-core-3.9.1-20220127.jar:3.9.1-20220127]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:210) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.9.1-20220127.jar:3.9.1-20220127]
    ... 15 more
Caused by: org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException: Failed to invoke lifecycle phase "initialise" on object: org.mule.module.apikit.Configuration@3fda8dae (org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:49) ~[mule-core-3.9.1-20220127.jar:3.9.1-20220127]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69) ~[mule-core-3.9.1-20220127.jar:3.9.1-20220127]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.autoConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:102) ~[mule-core-3.9.1-20220127.jar:3.9.1-20220127]
    
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.doCreateMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:222) ~[mule-core-3.9.1-20220127.jar:3.9.1-20220127]
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:81) ~[mule-core-3.9.1-20220127.jar:3.9.1-20220127]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:210) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.9.1-20220127.jar:3.9.1-20220127]
    ... 15 more
Caused by: org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException: Failed to invoke lifecycle phase "initialise" on object: org.mule.module.apikit.Configuration@3fda8dae
    at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistry.initialise(AbstractRegistry.java:126) ~[mule-core-3.9.1-20220127.jar:3.9.1-20220127]
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.createSpringRegistry(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:177) ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.9.1-20220127.jar:3.9.1-20220127]
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:100) ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.9.1-20220127.jar:3.9.1-20220127]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:43) ~[mule-core-3.9.1-20220127.jar:3.9.1-20220127]

    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.doCreateMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:222) ~[mule-core-3.9.1-20220127.jar:3.9.1-20220127]
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:81) ~[mule-core-3.9.1-20220127.jar:3.9.1-20220127]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:210) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.9.1-20220127.jar:3.9.1-20220127]
    ... 15 more
Caused by: org.mule.api.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Failed to invoke lifecycle phase "initialise" on object: org.mule.module.apikit.Configuration@3fda8dae
    at org.mule.lifecycle.phases.DefaultLifecyclePhase.applyLifecycle(DefaultLifecyclePhase.java:243) ~[mule-core-3.9.1-20220127.jar:3.9.1-20220127]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.phases.MuleContextInitialisePhase.applyLifecycle(MuleContextInitialisePhase.java:71) ~[mule-core-3.9.1-20220127.jar:3.9.1-20220127]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleCallback.doApplyLifecycle(RegistryLifecycleCallback.java:108) ~[mule-core-3.9.1-20220127.jar:3.9.1-20220127]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleCallback.onTransition(RegistryLifecycleCallback.java:78) ~[mule-core-3.9.1-20220127.jar:3.9.1-20220127]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager.invokePhase(AbstractLifecycleManager.java:146) ~[mule-core-3.9.1-20220127.jar:3.9.1-20220127]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager.fireLifecycle(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:134) ~[mule-core-3.9.1-20220127.jar:3.9.1-20220127]
    at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistry.fireLifecycle(AbstractRegistry.java:150) ~[mule-core-3.9.1-20220127.jar:3.9.1-20220127]
    at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistry.initialise(AbstractRegistry.java:116) ~[mule-core-3.9.1-20220127.jar:3.9.1-20220127]
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.createSpringRegistry(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:177) ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.9.1-20220127.jar:3.9.1-20220127]
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:100) ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.9.1-20220127.jar:3.9.1-20220127]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:43) ~[mule-core-3.9.1-20220127.jar:3.9.1-20220127]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69) ~[mule-core-3.9.1-20220127.jar:3.9.1-20220127]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.autoConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:102) ~[mule-core-3.9.1-20220127.jar:3.9.1-20220127]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:54) ~[mule-core-3.9.1-20220127.jar:3.9.1-20220127]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:43) ~[mule-core-3.9.1-20220127.jar:3.9.1-20220127]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69) ~[mule-core-3.9.1-20220127.jar:3.9.1-20220127]
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory$1.configure(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:89) ~[mule-core-3.9.1-20220127.jar:3.9.1-20220127]
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.doCreateMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:222) ~[mule-core-3.9.1-20220127.jar:3.9.1-20220127]
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:81) ~[mule-core-3.9.1-20220127.jar:3.9.1-20220127]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:210) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.9.1-20220127.jar:3.9.1-20220127]
    ... 15 more
Caused by: org.mule.module.apikit.exception.ApikitRuntimeException: Invalid API descriptor -- errors found: 1

Raml parser uncaught exception: org.raml.yagi.framework.nodes.StringNodeImpl cannot be cast to org.raml.yagi.framework.nodes.KeyValueNode

    at org.mule.module.apikit.parser.ParserWrapperV2.validate(ParserWrapperV2.java:73) ~[mule-module-apikit-3.9.1.jar:?]
    at org.mule.module.apikit.ParserService.validateRaml(ParserService.java:86) ~[mule-module-apikit-3.9.1.jar:?]
    at org.mule.module.apikit.AbstractConfiguration.initialise(AbstractConfiguration.java:112) ~[mule-module-apikit-3.9.1.jar:?]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor19.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.phases.DefaultLifecyclePhase.applyLifecycle(DefaultLifecyclePhase.java:230) ~[mule-core-3.9.1-20220127.jar:3.9.1-20220127]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.phases.MuleContextInitialisePhase.applyLifecycle(MuleContextInitialisePhase.java:71) ~[mule-core-3.9.1-20220127.jar:3.9.1-20220127]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleCallback.doApplyLifecycle(RegistryLifecycleCallback.java:108) ~[mule-core-3.9.1-20220127.jar:3.9.1-20220127]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleCallback.onTransition(RegistryLifecycleCallback.java:78) ~[mule-core-3.9.1-20220127.jar:3.9.1-20220127]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager.invokePhase(AbstractLifecycleManager.java:146) ~[mule-core-3.9.1-20220127.jar:3.9.1-20220127]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager.fireLifecycle(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:134) ~[mule-core-3.9.1-20220127.jar:3.9.1-20220127]
    at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistry.fireLifecycle(AbstractRegistry.java:150) ~[mule-core-3.9.1-20220127.jar:3.9.1-20220127]
    at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistry.initialise(AbstractRegistry.java:116) ~[mule-core-3.9.1-20220127.jar:3.9.1-20220127]
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.createSpringRegistry(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:177) ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.9.1-20220127.jar:3.9.1-20220127]
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:100) ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.9.1-20220127.jar:3.9.1-20220127]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:43) ~[mule-core-3.9.1-20220127.jar:3.9.1-20220127]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69) ~[mule-core-3.9.1-20220127.jar:3.9.1-20220127]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.autoConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:102) ~[mule-core-3.9.1-20220127.jar:3.9.1-20220127]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:54) ~[mule-core-3.9.1-20220127.jar:3.9.1-20220127]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:43) ~[mule-core-3.9.1-20220127.jar:3.9.1-20220127]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69) ~[mule-core-3.9.1-20220127.jar:3.9.1-20220127]
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory$1.configure(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:89) ~[mule-core-3.9.1-20220127.jar:3.9.1-20220127]
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.doCreateMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:222) ~[mule-core-3.9.1-20220127.jar:3.9.1-20220127]
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:81) ~[mule-core-3.9.1-20220127.jar:3.9.1-20220127]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:210) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.9.1-20220127.jar:3.9.1-20220127]
    ... 15 more
INFO  2022-07-06 13:41:55,755 [main] org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher: 
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Mule is up and kicking (every 5000ms)                    +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
INFO  2022-07-06 13:41:55,762 [main] org.mule.module.launcher.StartupSummaryDeploymentListener: 
**********************************************************************
*              - - + DOMAIN + - -               * - - + STATUS + - - *
**********************************************************************
* default                                       * DEPLOYED           *
**********************************************************************

*******************************************************************************************************
*            - - + APPLICATION + - -            *       - - + DOMAIN + - -       * - - + STATUS + - - *
*******************************************************************************************************
* test-3.9.1                                    * default                        * FAILED             *
*******************************************************************************************************

DEBUG StatusLogger Stopping LoggerContext[name=test-3.9.1, org.mule.module.launcher.log4j2.MuleLoggerContext@589fb74d]...
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering 1 MBeans: [org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=test-3.9.1]
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering 1 MBeans: [org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=test-3.9.1,component=StatusLogger]
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering 1 MBeans: [org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=test-3.9.1,component=ContextSelector]
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering 10 MBeans: [org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=test-3.9.1,component=Loggers,name=Tracking, org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=test-3.9.1,component=Loggers,name=org.apache, org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=test-3.9.1,component=Loggers,name=org.springframework.beans.factory, org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=test-3.9.1,component=Loggers,name=org.apache.cxf, org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=test-3.9.1,component=Loggers,name=org.jetel, org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=test-3.9.1,component=Loggers,name=com.mulesoft.mule.transport.jdbc, org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=test-3.9.1,component=Loggers,name=org.mule, org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=test-3.9.1,component=Loggers,name=, org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=test-3.9.1,component=Loggers,name=com.mulesoft, org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=test-3.9.1,component=Loggers,name=org.mule.module.http.internal.HttpMessageLogger]
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering 2 MBeans: [org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=test-3.9.1,component=Appenders,name=Forced-Console, org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=test-3.9.1,component=Appenders,name=file]
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=test-3.9.1,component=AsyncAppenders,name=*'
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=test-3.9.1,component=AsyncLoggerRingBuffer'
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering 10 MBeans: [org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=test-3.9.1,component=Loggers,name=Tracking,subtype=RingBuffer, org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=test-3.9.1,component=Loggers,name=com.mulesoft,subtype=RingBuffer, org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=test-3.9.1,component=Loggers,name=org.jetel,subtype=RingBuffer, org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=test-3.9.1,component=Loggers,name=org.springframework.beans.factory,subtype=RingBuffer, org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=test-3.9.1,component=Loggers,name=org.mule,subtype=RingBuffer, org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=test-3.9.1,component=Loggers,name=org.apache.cxf,subtype=RingBuffer, org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=test-3.9.1,component=Loggers,name=org.mule.module.http.internal.HttpMessageLogger,subtype=RingBuffer, org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=test-3.9.1,component=Loggers,name=org.apache,subtype=RingBuffer, org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=test-3.9.1,component=Loggers,name=com.mulesoft.mule.transport.jdbc,subtype=RingBuffer, org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=test-3.9.1,component=Loggers,name=,subtype=RingBuffer]
DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'Converter' found 44 plugins

TRACE StatusLogger XmlConfiguration notifying ReliabilityStrategies that appenders will be stopped.
TRACE StatusLogger XmlConfiguration stopping remaining Appenders.
DEBUG StatusLogger Shutting down RollingFileManager C:\Local\mule3-workspace\.mule\logs\test-3.9.1.log
DEBUG StatusLogger Shutting down RollingFileManager C:\Local\mule3-workspace\.mule\logs\test-3.9.1.log
DEBUG StatusLogger All asynchronous threads have terminated
DEBUG StatusLogger RollingFileManager shutdown completed with status true
DEBUG StatusLogger Shut down RollingFileManager C:\Local\mule3-workspace\.mule\logs\test-3.9.1.log, all resources released: true
DEBUG StatusLogger Appender file stopped with status true
DEBUG StatusLogger Appender Forced-Console stopped with status true
TRACE StatusLogger XmlConfiguration stopped 2 remaining Appenders.
TRACE StatusLogger XmlConfiguration cleaning Appenders from 11 LoggerConfigs.
DEBUG StatusLogger Stopped XmlConfiguration[location=C:\Local\mule3-workspace\.mule\apps\test-3.9.1\classes\log4j2.xml] OK
DEBUG StatusLogger Stopped LoggerContext[name=test-3.9.1, org.mule.module.launcher.log4j2.MuleLoggerContext@4458ecb8] with status true
```

Update about the issue, so even after updating the apikit module in the pom and manually to 3.9.3 it's still showing in the error logs the next;

```
After updating the apikit in the pom I saw that it still not using the new version;

Caused by: org.mule.module.apikit.exception.ApikitRuntimeException: Invalid API descriptor -- errors found: 1

Raml parser uncaught exception: org.raml.yagi.framework.nodes.StringNodeImpl cannot be cast to org.raml.yagi.framework.nodes.KeyValueNode

    at org.mule.module.apikit.parser.ParserWrapperV2.validate(ParserWrapperV2.java:73) ~[mule-module-apikit-3.9.1.jar:?].
```

Answer (score 0):

The RAML parser for Mule 3 is not as modern as the one for Mule 4. There are also bugs that are fixed in later versions/releases for any given version.

You can use a newer version of APIKit as long as it is compatible with the Mule version. Mule 4 releases of APIKit are not compatible with Mule 3. However if the RAML is working for APIKit 3.9.3 you could use it with Mule 3.9.1, as its [release notes](https://docs.mulesoft.com/release-notes/apikit/apikit-3.9.3-release-notes) say it is compatible with Mule 3.9.1.

Comment: even if I change the version in the pom to use 3.9.3 or 3.9.5 which also compatible still the same error. Only if I choose the runtime 3.9.3 than it runs fine.

Comment: I forgot that APIKit for Mule 3 is built in the runtime. Do you mean that running the application with any Mule 3.9 version other than 3.9.3 triggers the same error?

Comment: No, like I said it's only with 3.9.1. There must be a work around that i cant see now